# How to perform calculation on a model attribute with input for form in django

Tags: django, model, calculation

I'm new to Python/ Django here, but working hard

To train myself, I'm working on a simple View that would
-take input through a form (DecimalField)
-Pass it to the View, where it perform calculation based on my Class Method
-Display it on my template, below to the InputForm itself and next to my other Class/Object attributes

++CODE UPDATE++ the value from the Form is intercepted and transmitted back to the template through {data} but I cannot pass it the the Model method...Where should I put the function instancing in the views ? or maybe I have an identation problem...

in the end,  my template would look like :

```
<br>
{% for list in list %}<br>
<div> {{ list.price }} <div> <div> {{ list.newprice}} <br><br>
```

with the css I'm already using of course

Models:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cost = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def newprice(self, input):
        newprice = self.price * input
        return newprice
```

Form:

```
class MultiplierForm(forms.Form):
    multiplier = forms.IntegerField(label='Your cost')
```

View:

```
def multi(request):
    list = Product.objects.all()
    data = 0
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MultiplierForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = request.POST.get('value_from_form')

    else : form = MultiForm(request.POST or None)

    p = Product.newprice() ##this code crash the server. 
                           ##If you I it above the else :form the template display
                           ## but crashes when I submit a value with a   
                           ## Function is Missing Argument error
    p(data)

    return render(request, 'viewinventory/multi.html', {'form': form, 'list': list, 'data': data})
```

++CODE UPDATE++ the value from the Form is intercepted and transmitted back to the template through {data} but I cannot pass it the the Model method...Where should I put the function instancing in the views ? or maybe I have an identation problem...
I wish to remain simple and avoid going to uncharted territory like filter and all

Comment: Do you want to save the value or do you just want to display it? EDIT: Also, do you want to multiply all prices in the list based on the same multiplier, or do you wish for people to be able to set different multipliers for different products?

Comment: I do not need to save the Input Value. I just need to intercept it from the MultiplierForm, pass it to Model method function (so it returns a list.newprice value I can display in the template with a loop of all product in the list)

I think I'm a bit lost on the syntax I must use in my views to capture the input value and pass it to the multiplier method function

Answer (score 0):

In the Django it is said that **"Fat models, thin views, stupid templates, and utility modules."**

So basically your view may be thin and you can write your calculation logic inside other **utility** method or inside the **model**.

But obviously you can do either you could write your code inside your **views.py** or write it inside `Model` class / *utility method*.

I would suggest to write your calculation on other utility function or from `Django` model. It would be quite simple way as **"Thin views and Fat model"** concept.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to do this, but I think a template filter might be the simplest and most flexible way.

**Get the value:**

First, to get the multiplier value from the form you just pick it from the request like this:

```
multiplier = request.POST.get('multiplier', 1)
# 1 is set as default value if the value was not found.
```

Then you can pass this value on to your template through the context dictionary.

```
return render(request, 
'inventory/index.html', {'form': form, 'list': list, 'multiplier': multiplier},)
```

Your code would look like this:

```
def index(request):
    form = MultiplierForm()
    list = Product.objects.all() 
    multiplier = 0       

    if request.method == "POST":
        multiplier = request.POST.get('multiplier', 1)
        form.multiplier = multiplier

    return render(request, inventory/index.html', {'form': form, 'list': list, 'multiplier': multiplier},)
```

**Create and use the filter:**

Now you need to create a custom filter that you can use in your templates.

If you don't have one already, create a folder called `templatetags` on the same directory level as your `templates` folder. (Inside the templatetags folder, create a file called `__init__.py`. This file can be empty, but it has to be there.)
Inside the templatetags folder, create a file called `my_tags.py` (name is optional) and inside that file you write your template tags and filters.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def new_price(price, multiplier):
    return price * multiplier
```

Then at the top of your template you have to load the template tags like this:

```
{% load my_tags %}
```

Then you can use the filter like this where you want to put the new price:

```
<p>New Price: {{product.price | new_price:multiplier}}</p>
```

This will pass `product.price` to the filter function `new_price` with `multiplier` as the second argument, and the function will return `price * multiplier`.

**Extras:**

Now, if you want to only show the new price if the multiplier has been set, then you can modify your template like this:

```
{% if multiplier > 0 %}<p>New Price: {{product.price | new_price:multiplier}}</p>{% endif %}
```

**EDIT:**

You can read more about template tags and filters here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/